# Python If Statement Error, in bash_profile function

Tags: python, bash

I am very new to python and am trying to use it to parse a file with JSON in it within my bash_profile script, and return the value.  I can't seem to get the if statement working. It will read the contents of the file, but I recieve this error, with an arrow under the if statement.

```
File "<string>", line 1
    import sys,json;data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read());if data['123456789']:print...
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Contents of File:

```
{"123456789":"Well Hello"}
```

Function that searches file:

```
function find_it {
  file=~/.pt_branches
  CURRENT_CONTENTS=`cat $file`
  echo $CURRENT_CONTENTS | python -c "import sys,json;data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read());if data['$1']:print data['$1'];else:print '';"
}
```

Command

```
find_it "123456789"
```

If I were to remove the if statement and just return the value, it does work, but I want it to be able to return and empty string if it does not exist.

```
echo $CURRENT_CONTENTS | python -c "import sys,json;data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read());print data['$1'];"
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code golf!

```
"import sys, json; data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print data.get('$1') or ''"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
echo $CURRENT_CONTENTS | python -c "                                                                                                                            
import sys
import json
data = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())
if data['$1']:
    print data['$1']
else:
    print ''"
```